# What are the bounds of Lo Tisgodedu?

Tags: minhag

The concept of "Lo Tisgodedu" is homiletically interpreted to "lo ta'asu agudos agudos" - do not make distinct groups. This is used in a variety of places, most notably in the principal that one does not publicly deviate from minhag hamakom.

[As discussed elsewhere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81436/ashkenazi-sephardi-etc-a-violation-of-lo-titgodedu), this doesn't seem to impede the creation of local/regional minhagim. What is the "upper bound" to the implementation of this concept, and how do we resolve conflicting minhagim within a pluralistic group with no minhag hamakom (Rav Moshe, IIRC, claims that the US is such a situation)?

Comment: "most notably in the principal that one does not publicly deviate from minhag hamakom." Where is it used like that? I don't see it referenced in the fourth chapter of Pesachim, which is the main source of laws of minhag hamakom.

Comment: @DoubleAA Many situations use this principal, like wearing tefillin in a chol hamoed minyan when your minhag is different from the prevailing one.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not an issue of differing minhagim but of differing psak halakha. Deviating from minhag hamakom is a different issue and I still see no evidence of Lo Titgodedu being used therein.